# add properties to a class in execution time in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object

I have a problem, i execute a dinamic t-sql query that returns a pivot-table like:

```
code      description   Price  col1   col2   col3   col4    col5 ............. column n

acx       cable1         123    2      0      0      0       1

bbb       vitro          35     0      1      0      58      0
```

and i think to create a class like this:

```
public class excelInventory
        {
            public string code { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public decimal col1 { get; set; }
            public decimal col2 { get; set; }
            public decimal col3 { get; set; }
            public decimal col4 { get; set; }
            public decimal col5 { get; set; }
         }
```

then i read from the result of the query with a dataReader and inser in a List of excelInventory:

```
 SqlDataReader oDataReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
            List<excelInventory> excelin = new List<excelInventory>();
    while (oDataReader.Read())
                {
                    excelInventory inv = new excelInventory();
                    inv.code = oDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    inv.description = oDataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(2).ToString())) { inv.stock = 0; }
                    else { inv.stock = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(2).ToString()); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(3).ToString())) { inv.precio = 0; }
                    else { inv.precio = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(3).ToString()); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(4).ToString())) { inv.col1 = 0; }
                    else { inv.col1 = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(4).ToString()); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(5).ToString())) { inv.col2 = 0; }
                    else { inv.col2 = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(5).ToString()); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(6).ToString())) { inv.col3 = 0; }
                    else { inv.col3 = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(6).ToString()); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(7).ToString())) { inv.col4 = 0; }
                    else { inv.col4 = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(7).ToString()); }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oDataReader.GetValue(8).ToString())) { inv.col5 = 0; }
                    else { inv.col5 = decimal.Parse(oDataReader.GetValue(8).ToString()); 

excelin.Add(inv);//Add the object to a list

}
```

but the problema is that the number of columns returned not always the same so i need to modify the program code to change the number of properties of the class, maybe the next time i launch the sql query returns 10 columns, so this is not valid.

I don´t know if i can add properties to excelInventory in execution time, so i´m thinking to use a bidimensional Array,i can declare the array after the datareader and use dataReader.FieldCount to know the number of columns.

But how i declare the array and how i redimension the array while Reading de dataReader acording to the number of rows?

Comment: can you provide code with `dataReader`?

Comment: changed the title, i want to know if it is possible to add properties to a class in execution time and if it´s not how can i use a bidimensional array

Comment: You could use either a List of decimals (List<decimal>) or a dynamic keyword to define an expando object. In the last case you are also free to give different names for properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use arrays and to find the size of array you can use how many no of rows are there in `datatable` and how many columns are present. However, I would prefer using a `List<decimal>` so I don't have to worry about the no of columns returned by `datatable`. The code with this solution would look something like

```
public class excelInventory
        {
            public excelInventory(){
                cols = new List<decimal>();
            }
            public string code { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public List<decimal> cols{get;set;}
         }
```

First you need to initialize the list. you can do it in constructor as I did in modified code after your comment. then when you assign values to `cols`, you need to follow following syntax

```
cols.Add(dr.getValue(2));   //you can access this element later by cols[0]
cols.Add(dr.getValue(3));   //you can access this element later by cols[1]
```

Comment: I like this solution, sounds great, but when i want to add diferents data to cols, How i do it???, something like cols[0]=dr.getvalue(2)????